I'm struggling to find better weapon upgrades than my starter gear in Monster Hunter Rise; what am I missing?
I've been playing Monster Hunter Rise for the last few days. Generally, that game gives me a lot of fun; however, I feel that I don't get the rules.
The most interesting are, for me, weapons and their upgrades. From the beginning of the game, my character wears a totally better armor set than the others, which I saw in the blacksmith's offers. I noticed the same situation with weapons. I'm still fighting with the blades I have from the beginning of the game because there is no better weapon anywhere.
I've unlocked some upgrades for other types of blades, but they're still much weaker than mine. Is it okay, or did I miss something? 

Are you looking at the weapons "for sale"? In Monster Hunter you get your weapon and armor upgrades by forging your own. What is the name of the weapon you are using?

Hmm, yes, I wrote about weapons which we can forge/upgrade. I wear Defender Dual Blades I, but a a few moments ago finally crafted other pair of blades (Bone Hatchets I) which has not so bad stats, comparing with Defender Dual Blades I. So maybe I can assumed that will be able to craft stronger weapon soon. But now, the big difference I see in armors. I wear Black Belt S set and it is incredibly better than all stuff offered to craft by blacksmith in the village.

Are you perhaps wielding Defender Weapons, or wearing Black Belt armor?
These weapons / armors are designed to be the best in slot for Low / High rank quests, because they came out with Sunbreak and are designed to catapult players through Low / High rank to the new Master rank quests.
You are not missing anything -- you're just getting a different experience because you're playing post-Sunbreak, rather than Rise on release. Once you get to Master Rank (or even, the upper end of High Rank), you'll be unable to upgrade the gear further, and you'll need to switch to standard gear if you want to progress.

Thanks, I didn't expect that, because I dont have Sunbreak. But as I understand, Monster Hunter is game where multiplayer is important, so it works similar to character boost in World of Worcraft, which allows to explore a new content from the newest expansion.

@TravelerVihaan That's an excellent analogy! Yes, exactly so!
